# how to deal with difficult students who do not reply to teacher's email?

Tags: teaching, communication, teaching-assistant, lab-management

I hope all is well,

I find myself in a situation where one student keeps a grim face when I teach. It seems he is not happy with the way I deliver the material. This makes me feel uncomfortable and it affects my mood.

I tried to be nice and accomodating. I also tried to explain why I could not run the session the way he pleased. However, instead of understanding, he used the arguments I provided against me to my senior colleague who took his stand and started to point out the problems and the negative feedback I received and ignore the positive ones.

I understand that there is room for improvements, but it seems that dealing with a superior whereby he takes an extreme view of one student is very emotionally challenging and is causing me mental distress.

My senior colleague is a perfectionist typed individual who likes everything perfect. It is tricky first to teach a particular class to make things perfect from the first time. However, my colleague does not seem to be kind in pointing this out or appreciating the positive feedback. It is tough to impress him. I need to impress him so that he does not write a negative comment on my performance. I can say that I am learning a lot, though and I appreciate both the comments of my senior and that of the student.

However, the student does not want to give details on what is staggering him with the teaching. He does not like my teaching and delivery, but he does not want to engage or inform me what is puzzling him or how I could help him or improve my delivery. He just wants to complain.

I tried sending him an email as a gesture that I was willing to hear him and informed him that I stood by his side, but he decided to ignore my email and my presence during the session entirely.

Although he comes to class, he completely ignores my presence, smiling and laughing with his colleagues. All is fine, but it came to the point where he spoke to my support colleagues, discussing lets say not nice stuff. This annoyed me, but I kept my patience to understand how to deal with such challenges in academia pedagogically.

I have many students who mostly are happy with my module and delevery, but some are not, which is normally the case in any module. I really tried to be helpful, but he is not engaging, and I do not know how to approach him anymore.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you the professor for the course or a TA? How does a student seem to have such power?

Comment: @Buffy I am the teacher not TA

Comment: "My senior colleague is a perfectionist individual who likes everything perfect. [..] It is tough to impress him. "
why would you like to impress him?

Comment: I guess I am not clear what the problem is; having a few students who openly dislike the teacher is not so unusual, especially in large, lower-level classes with less experienced instructors. Is this student disrupting your class? Is the student's behavior undermining your reputation with your colleagues / administration? Is your "senior colleague" doing so? Are you worried about getting fired?

Comment: @cag51 and EarlGrey I paraphrased my answer. I do not understand why I am voted downward. Is my question wrong or inappropriate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here, an educational issue and a political one. They may be at odds.

For the educational issue, I'd let further communication with the student go until it becomes necessary. Not every student will be pleased with you no matter what you do since there are differences in how individuals learn. A brilliant student might not actually need any lectures at all. But there is little point in arguing with them, and making changes to suit a single person will likely displease others.

I'm a bit more concerned about your senior colleague. If they have power over you then you may just have to go along with their (misplaced) ideas to some extent. However...

There are very few students who will learn anything with a single "perfect" statement of it. I have evidence from my own long history that it just doesn't work. Anything with any complexity at all requires reinforcement. Some of that reinforcement is just saying things in different ways and using analogy and metaphor to give a general idea along with the technical. Another reinforcement mechanism is student exercises that the student gets feedback on. Not just grades. Perhaps your senior colleague doesn't understand any of that, though I can't diagnose at a distance.

Your job (IMO) is to teach every student. What that means is setting the conditions in which learning can occur if the student is willing to put in the effort. Not all will, and some will prefer that you do things differently. Setting the conditions means more than just providing information. Wikipedia does that sort of thing pretty well, but is inadequate for real learning - especially for novice learners.

(Note that a previous US vice-president used "setting the conditions" as a euphemism for torture. I think about that sometimes.)

As an example, from mathematics, of the perfect being the enemy of the good, the formal definition of the derivative of a real valued function is incomprehensible to students on first reading, though it is perfectly concise and correct. It takes even good students quite a long time to *grok* it properly. Why does it have this structure? What are the implications? What does it tell us about the behavior of functions? It is a magic incantation for a while and takes a lot of work to sort it out. True, a student can memorize it without understanding, but that isn't learning.

Answer (score -1):

As a perfectionist who is sometimes someone's senior colleague... You have been told you're not doing a good job. Your question makes it sound more about your struggle and less about the issue at hand, which, I believe, a perfectionist would have a huuuge issue with. "It is hard" is not an argument that lands well with people like myself. Sure, it is hard, so what? Do you outright refuse to work towards that goal? Well, this is precisely what bad reviews are for! There is nothing inherently bad in getting one, by the way -
you are free to choose to spend more effort and get a good review or spend less effort and get a bad one, if you decide that the demands are unreasonable.

To deal with the senior colleague, you would need to provide an outline of how are you going to respond to this issue. The one they will approve of - that will also potentially be a big learning opportunity for you. If they actually have brought up the authority/seniority card before, even better! They would almost surely love to pass their experience on, and hate being argued with. Do not think poorly of it based on the interaction alone - their knowledge is often bona fide very valuable.

In the process of doing so, **leverage your senior colleague to deal with that student**. Instead of assuming a defensive stance which is unsustainable - indeed, the biggest problem listed in your question is "he just wants to complain". Say that you are willing to work with this student. Try your best to help them. Evidently, approaching them directly did not help. Ask your senior colleague: "I would like to help, but I do not even know where to start, I do not know what are they unhappy with and how to accommodate them better. What would you do/What should I do?" Try to be cool-headed and not let emotions heavily impact your first responses. You are not getting anywhere by shielding yourself from further interactions and being dismissive.

And if anything, if your colleague's approach also fails, it would be a lot harder for them to blame it on you.